# Best Design Pattern for a WPF MVVM application

Tags: wpf, design-patterns, mvvm

I´m developping a project using WPF + MVVM.
The program needs to load objects (cases) from a repository and allow the user to edit it.
The main functionalities are:

- CRUD of cases
- Know which cases have been loaded
- Know which case is currently selected

Currently, the version 0.1 uses a singleton class Session (in namespace model) to store a list from all cases loaded.

There is also a "Case Management" service that perform several operations in the Session singleton:

- Load a case from the repository and store it in Session
- Remove cases
- Verify if a case is valid
- Select a case for editing

I´m new to WPF, and I would like to know if there is a design pattern that is suitable for this situation. I´m afraid that I´m not going to the right direction.

I dont know if I have provided all information needed, but I´m willing to answer any question as fast as I can.

[image: Here if a prototype]

[image: Example of a Load operation]

Comment: What is the purpose of storing cases into the singleton class?

Comment: Every ViewModel access the same session.

Comment: Can you replace the singleton with a service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your design is fine, i can't see anything wrong.

I would suggest one thing though, get rid of that singleton session object and use dependency injection, and let the DI container decide what life strategy to use for the Session object at the application composition root.

Answer (score 1):

I hope your case management service is using some kind of ORM . If yes, then it will automatically take care of your Load Case/ Return Case and storing it into the session. And depending on user input when you want to get something from the session and you can use Dependency Injection principle (i would suggest to use Ninject) and achieve it with a singleton pattern .